# Search for a string with inconsistent inner characters, but consistent outer ones

Tags: python-2.7, full-text-search

How would you construct a search in order to look for a string where the outer characters are consistent, but the inner ones could change?

For example, suppose I have this text (and a lot of other text like it):

```
In January 2015, I went for a walk.
In June 2005, I went for a jog.
During December 2000, they went for a drive.
```

I want to search for the year. The only things I know that are consistent are the presence of the year, followed by a comma.

How would I search for '20xy,' where xy could be anything for 00 to 17?

Edit: Searching for just '20' (or variations of) is no good, as the number 20 may appear earlier in the text of one of the documents I'm working with.

Edit 2: 
What I'm after is the index of the first instance that the year appears where it is followed by a comma. The year could be anything from 2000 to present, but the comma is always present. If the year appears earlier in the string without a comma, then we ignore it.

```
 eg. The year is 2000 and this is followed by 2001, when I went swimming.
```

In this example, I want to ignore 2000 and find 2001.

Comment: I need more examples of what you would want your search to bring up and what it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions re.search() first looking for 200[0-9], then 201[0-7],